# i can seem to figure out whats wrong with this variance for loop

Tags: c++

Every time I try to find the variance with this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    variance += (arr[i] - average) * 2;
}
```

I keep getting the error

> variance is being used without being initialized

I defined it with a `double` in the beginning.

Comment: Did you define it as `double variance = 0.0;` ?

Comment: double variance; do i need to define it as double variance=0?

Comment: keep in mind that when u declare var in c++ it just reads rubbish it found in memory where it was created

Comment: thanks it fixed the problem, {33.5, 67.5, 67.5, 88.0, 46.0, 94.5, 77.5, 83.0, 95.0, 80.5} this is my array and i calculated the variance by hand and its comes out to 369.66 but the programs runs it gets something way off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your variable a value before you can add anything to it, because

```
double variance;
```

will leave you with a variable with some random numbers (check this by printing, or debugging it)

Try this:

```
double variance = 0.0;
```

Comment: thanks it fixed the problem, {33.5, 67.5, 67.5, 88.0, 46.0, 94.5, 77.5, 83.0, 95.0, 80.5} this is my array and i calculated the variance by hand and its comes out to 369.66 but the programs runs it gets something way off